# Hook to overlap two image in product loop page and single page in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working with a T-Shirt Designing Plugin and going to merge it with woocommerce plugin.
In which i have to overlap two image as bellow.

1. White T-shirt ( set by admin which will always same for all product).
2. T-shirt Logo  (uploaded by designer as product image when uploading his product from front end and the details will goes to woocommerce product section ).

The T-shirt logo will be on the top of the white T-Shirt.

Is there any Hook to overlap this two image in product single page and product loop page in woocommerce.

Comment: there arent any hooks to do what you want. Either you can show it using CSS manipulations by overlapping to Images. Or other way is, you create a composite image from the two images using image processing. ex: Imagick Library

Comment: the logo image will be dynamic for every product so i have to merge the logo image with t-shirt image for every time dynamical.... how to dynamically fetch two image(t-shrt image will be same every-time) for every product??

Comment: use logo image as product image and add tshirt image to post_meta with some key. In that way you will have two different images. Now u need to show the combined one to user. which option will you prefer from the ones I mentioned

Comment: i did image overlapping by css. As it is dynamic and i do not want to write code on woocommerec plugin. I told that i am doing  another plugin where i want code everything even css also. So i want add some hook function on my plugin page which merge with woocommerce i already manage the meta field all. But as i will not code on woocommerce plugin i need some external code which merge with woocommerce.

Comment: you can use woocommerce hooks in your plugin to add required functionality

Comment: yes i am telling about that hook, if u know please share it.

Comment: what exactly do you want to accomplish and where ? according to that, you can choose the hook. be specific

Comment: i want this overlapped image in both page product loop page and product single page

Comment: I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are no specific hooks for the same.

Store 2 images : 1 as product image, other in post_meta for that product.

you can over lap the two images as over here : you can use CSS to overlap 2 images like the one I did here : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iJmtn

For changing Image in product loop, you will need to remove the default woocommerce hook for product thumbnail.

`remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );`

And add your custom hook output your required markup.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'your_function', 10 );

function your_function(){
//your code
}
```

For changing the image for the single product page, there is a template in woocommerce `single-product/product-image.php`. you will need to override that template to out your required markup